# XNOR gate with multiple inputs

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Suppose In a 5-inputs XNOR gate, the inputs are 0,1,x,0,and 1. how can I determined the output is?

Comment: Do you understand how a 3-input XOR works?

Comment: yes I understand it in terms of XOR, it's a odd function if the inputs are different the output is 1

Comment: @ZhuangzhuangLi your definition is not rignt. `XOR` will has `1` on output just when odd number of inputs are `1`. `XOR` works like simple `+`

Answer (score 1):

Your x in simulation is unknown. So the answer is unknown, x.

Answer (score 1):

A 5 inputs XNOR is equivalent to this scheme ( with only XOR ) :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO8f5J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

According to this, the output only depend of "x".